# I want to validate an array of objects for valid time values

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I'm trying to validate the following array of objects:
`[{from: '10:00', to: '16:00'}, null, {from: '09:00', to: '16:00'}, etc. ]`

I want exactly 7 objects in that array, how do I validate that? I guess adding both `.min(7)` and `.max(7)` is not the best practice. How can I let `NULL` values through as well?

Also is this other part good or would you change something? I'm new to JavaScript.

```
schedule: array().of(
    object().shape({
      from: string()
        .required()
        .matches(/^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):(00|30)$/),
      to: string()
        .required()
        .matches(/^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):(00|30)$/),
    })
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check something as a simple time value, i.e., `12:34`, you can use this regex: `/^[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}$/`.  Code:

```js
var item = '10:00';
console.log(item.match(/^[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}$/));
```

- `^` : Indicates the start of the string.
- `[0-5]`: Some character 0 to 5.
- `[0-5]{1}`: Some character 0 to 5, and exactly one of these.
- `[0-9]`: Some character from 0 to 9.
- `[0-9]{1}`: Some character from 0 to 9, and exactly one of these.
- `[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}`: Something between 00:00 and 59:59.
- `$` : Indicates the end of the string.

I have implemented it for your data structure.  Note: I added in a false value, so we could see it actually indicate invalid.

```js
var items = [
  {from: '10:00', to: '16:00'},
  null,
  {from: '09:00', to: '16:00'},
  {from: '09:00', to: '16:001234'}
];

items.forEach((item) => {
    logstring = "Item : ";
    if(!item) {
      logstring += 'NULL/VALID';
    } else {
      logstring += item.from + " " ;
      if(item.from.match(/^[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}$/)) {
          logstring += 'VALID';
      } else {
          logstring += 'INVALID';
      }
      
      logstring += ', ' + item.to + " " ;
      if(item.to.match(/^[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}$/)) {
          logstring += 'VALID';
      } else {
          logstring += 'INVALID';
      }
    }
    console.log(logstring);
});
```

Comment: the problem with that regex is that for example {from: '99:00', to: '16:74'} would validate as well

Comment: @Zselter: Hey, thanks for getting back!  You never defined what is "valid", and according to MySQL Docs, `99.00` is 100% a valid time value.  Source: [The TIME Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html)  Anyway, IF what you mean is a valid 24-hour format, then I've updated my answer.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use validation `is()` property. Here is the documentation link: https://validatejs.org/#validators-length

Comment: Pls Provide a demo link to this solution.